# Confusion regarding calculation of amount of water in container to ensure lowest centre of mass

Tags: mass, statics

When I tried to calculate the volume of water that should fill a massed container such that the centre of mass of the system is the lowest, I obtained two separate results when two different methods are used.

By a physical argument, the surface of the water should be at the centre of mass of the massed container to achieve the lowest centre of mass. This is because if more water is filled, the excess water would pull the centre of mass up; and when less water is filled, the centre of mass would be higher since the mass of the container would pull the centre of mass up.

By a mathematical argument, we can take the coordinates of the system as shown.

[image]

The CM of the system x is therefore given by the equation

$x=\frac{Mc+\rho A h^2/2}{M+\rho Ah}$

To find the minimum x, we find the point where the derivative is 0:

$\frac{(M+\rho A h)(\rho A h) - (Mc+\rho A h^2/2)(\rho A)}{(M+\rho A h)^2}= 0$

$M(h-c)+\frac{1}{2}\rho A h^2 = 0$

The solution to the first argument ($h=c$) clearly contradicts the equation of the second argument. However, I cannot see the fault with any of the argument presented.

Could anyone mind to tell me where is the conceptual error in any of my argument? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your first argument is flawed because when the surface of the water is at the CM of the container alone, it isn't true that removing some water pulls the combined CM higher.

For the lowest center of mass, the surface of the water needs to be at the CM of the *combined system*, not of the container alone. We will show this by arguing that either adding or removing water will pull the CM higher.

First, suppose you add some additional water. Call the combined system before extra water is added system $A$ (with the water level at the combined CM), and call any additional water you add system $B$. The since the CM of $A$ is at the previous water level and the CM of $B$ is higher than the previous water level, the CM of the new system $A+B$ is higher than system $A$ alone.

Finally, suppose that you remove some water. Call the water you remove system $B$, and let $A$ be the remaining system. The CM of $A+B$ is at the previous water level, and the CM of $B$ is lower than this level, so we conclude that the CM of $A$ (the system after removing water) must be higher than the previous water level.