# What is the physical explanation for $ cm(h_{min})= h_{min} $ when minimising the centre of mass of a can of coke?

Tags: mass, statics, optimization

There's an undergraduate statics problem that is about finding the lowest centre of mass of a coke can as it is emptied out (say through a weightless straw). The problem itself is not difficult and the solution is found by minimising the expression for the centre of mass: We define $H$ as the height of the can, $m_c$ the mass of the empty can, $r$ the radius of the can and $\rho$ the density of coke. If $h$ is the level of coke and taking into account the symmetry of the can, the c.m. of the system can be expressed as follows:

$$ cm(h) = \frac{\frac12Hm_c + \frac12\pi r^2\rho h^2}{m_c + \pi r^2\rho h}$$

The lowest centre of mass will satisfy $\frac{\partial{cm(h)}}{\partial h} = 0$, which yields:

$$ h_{min} = \frac{-2m_c \pm \sqrt{4 {m_c}^2 - 4 m_c H \pi r^2 \rho}}{2 \pi r^2
\rho} $$

If we check the height of the c.m. at $h_{min}$ we see that:

$$ cm(h_{min})= h_{min} $$

Which is surprising. Mathematically it just checks out, as if it were
a particular property of the function $cm(h)$. [This
question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/711866/confusion-regarding-calculation-of-amount-of-water-in-container-to-ensure-lowest)
explains the physical intuition as to why this happens, But I am after a more
rigourous explanation (if there is). I am assuming that there must be two
quantities that are equal when the level of coke reaches $h_{min}$. If this is
the case, what entities would they be? I have done some checks [on
desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/obolgo6cgt) and neither the masses nor
the first momenta of the can and the coke are equal at $h_{min}$.

Comment: I think $h_{min}$ is something more like $h_{critical}$, after all, the minimum of $h$ would correspond to no coke in the can, i.e. $h=0$.

Comment: Sometimes things like this happen, a function evaluated at its extremum is equal to the critical value at which the extremum is located, e.g. the function $f(x)=x^2$ is such that its critical value $x_c=0$ and $f(x_c)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

I like to think of the problem like this: start with an empty can. In this state the can has its center of mass directly at the midpoint. Now if I add a little coke, the addition places more mass at the bottom of the can, thereby shifting the center of mass a little from its previous location at the center. With each tiny addition I end up shifting the center of mass further and further down from the center until I reach the critical height; at precisely this point, any extra addition of coke will begin shifting the center of mass upwards toward the center where it will again be located if I fill the can completely up.